# HTML email - underline different colour from text

Tags: html, email, hyperlink

[image: Example of the different colour underline issue]

As in the image above, Links in my company's email footer have a different coloured text underline from the text colour. Does anyone know of a fix for this?

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `text decoration` attribute on links, and set a `border-bottom` with the color of your choice using CSS.

```
a {
   color:#000000;
   text-decoration: none; 
   border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.hyperlinkcode.com/change-underline-color.php:

```
<a href="change-underline-color.php" style="text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999">change underline color</a>
```